# How to make work a actionListener in a breadCrumb menuitem?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, breadcrumbs

I have the following code in an XHTML page :

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <p:breadCrumb>
        <p:menuitem value="Home" ajax="false" actionListener="#{menu.actionButton}"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Page 1" actionListener="#{menu.actionButton()}" ajax="false"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Page 2" url="#" />
    </p:breadCrumb>
</h:form>
```

In my bean menu the method :

```
public void actionButton() {
  System.out.println("OKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
}
```

If I call the method with a command button, it works fine but in menuitem the method is not call.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: `actionListener` with an absent pair of braces basically requires a `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` as a method argument. Try giving it to `actionButton()` and remove those braces in the middle `<p:menuitem>`.

Comment: Thank you it is working. I don't know if you can but if you want give your answer with the answer button then i can click answered and give you the points. kinds regards